Why we do SWAP operations for applying a mode N function in Shor algorithms and How we do this swapping?
I am working on implementing shor algorithm for finding prime factors of N = 15. I am trying to understand a code of qiskit, but i am confused how and why the code editor is using swap codes to define mode function. Here is the code:
def c_amod15(a, power):
    """Controlled multiplication by a mod 15"""
    if a not in [2,4,7,8,11,13]:
        raise ValueError("'a' must be 2,4,7,8,11 or 13")
    U = QuantumCircuit(4)
    for _iteration in range(power):
        if a in [2,13]:
            U.swap(2,3)
            U.swap(1,2)
            U.swap(0,1)
        if a in [7,8]:
            U.swap(0,1)
            U.swap(1,2)
            U.swap(2,3)
        if a in [4, 11]:
            U.swap(1,3)
            U.swap(0,2)
        if a in [7,11,13]:
            for q in range(4):
                U.x(q)
    U = U.to_gate()
    U.name = f"{a}^{power} mod 15"
    c_U = U.control()
    return c_U

